# Array in KineticJS

Tags: arrays, undefined, shapes, kineticjs

I'm fairly new to javascript and kinetic-js.

A while ago I created a script containing a Shape with Kinetic-js 3.9.0.
It was something like this (just the relevant code):

```
popup = new Kinetic.Shape({
  drawFunc: function() {
    item = itemlist[0];
  },
  itemlist: []
}
```

With 3.9.0 that worked in Firefox, but as of 3.9.2 it doesn't work any more.
Ther error console gives the message "TypeError: popup.itemlist is undefined".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize the itemlist variable after declaring the popup object.

It seems that Kinetic doesn't accepts user variables in their constructors methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.10.5.js"></script>

    <script>
        function draw() {
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container : "container",
                width : 800,
                height : 600
            });

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            var popup = new Kinetic.Shape({
                drawFunc: function(context) {
                    context.fillText(this.itemlist[0], 10,10);
                    context.fillText(this.itemlist[1], 10,50);
                    context.fillText(this.itemlist[2], 10,90);

                    this.fill(context);
                    this.stroke(context);       
                },
                fill: "red", 
                stroke: "green", strokeWidth:1
            });
            popup.itemlist = ["one", "two", "three"];

            layer.add(popup);

            // Add the layer to the stage
            stage.add(layer);
        };
        window.onload = draw;

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```